# How to make a toggle for switching text?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a button that switches the text in a `<p>` element. This is the HTML code:

`<button onclick="toggle()">Switch</button>
<p id="unit">metric</p>`

And this is the javaScript:

```
function toggle() {
      if(document.getElementById("unit").text()=="metric"){
          document.getElementById("unit").innerHTML="imperial";}

      else if(document.getElementById("unit").value=="imperial"){
          document.getElementById("unit").value="metric";}
      }
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would not rely on text for state. Use a property or class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the result of `innerHTML` for the check and for assingment.

While you have only two values, you need only one check.

```js
function toggle() {
    if (document.getElementById("unit").innerHTML === "metric") {
        document.getElementById("unit").innerHTML = "imperial";
    } else  {
        document.getElementById("unit").innerHTML = "metric";
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle()">Switch</button>
<p id="unit">metric</p>
```

A better version would take a variable for the actual value and toggle this value.

```js
function toggle() {
    unit = { metric: 'imperial', imperial: 'metric' }[unit];
    document.getElementById("unit").innerHTML = unit;
}

var unit = 'metric';
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle()">Switch</button>
<p id="unit">metric</p>
```

Comment: that is an object with a property, which toggels the unit.

Comment: that is the [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for the object `{ metric: 'imperial', imperial: 'metric' }`.

Comment: I like your suggested answer. To get rid of the global var you could adjust it just a bit to `this.unit = { metric: 'imperial', imperial: 'metric' }[this.unit] || "imperial";`

Comment: I thought so. But when I copy the line into console, it gives me `undefined`. `unit` is undefined. The whole line is cryptic for me. Why do you — not — use quotes for the keys. Can you explain the line step by step, please?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Just getting it. Needed the other `unit` variable. Genius.

Comment: it is not another variable, it is the only variable.

Answer (score 3):

Always use `.textContent` or `.innerHTML` unless you're dealing with an `input` or `textarea` element:

```js
function toggle() {
  const unit = document.getElementById("unit")
  if (unit.textContent === "metric") {
    unit.textContent = "imperial";
  } else if (unit.textContent === "imperial") {
    unit.textContent = "metric";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle()">Switch</button>
<p id="unit">metric</p>
```

Only use `innerHTML` when you're deliberately using or inserting HTML markup (which can have security and encoding problems). When you're setting or retrieving text values, use `textContent` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the `else if` you are setting `value` on the `#unit` where you should be setting `innerHTML` or `textContent`.

So this: `document.getElementById("unit").value="metric";` should be `document.getElementById("unit").innerHTML="metric";`

- EDIT(changed innerText to textContent as mentioned in comment by @CertainPerformance)

Comment: `innerText` is a quirky nonstandard property that IE introduced. It is highly recommended to instead use the standard, quicker, more reliable `textContent` instead - see http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText. Also, don't use `innerHTML` unless you're deliberately inserting HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

If you're swapping back and forth between two options you can use this pattern which minimizes the checking portion. It doesn't take into account any external changes on the text, but if all you want to do is swap the two values it will work well.

`&&` looks for the first falsy value, which is why `this.toggled` is set to true only when the property is `undefined`(a.e. the first time the function runs), after that it just changes its value to the opposite of whatever it currently is(`false=>true`, `true=>false`) and the text is displayed based on the updated value.

```js
function toggle() { 
  var p = document.getElementById("unit");

  this.toggled == undefined && (this.toggled = true)
  this.toggled = !this.toggled;
  
  p.textContent = (this.toggled) ? "metric" : "imperial";
};
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle()">Switch</button>
<p id="unit">metric</p>
```